# Combine multiple adjoining parts of a single feature

Tags: qgis, features

[image: The upper image shows the "single" feature selected and two nodes moved to the left to show a gap between its separate polygons (0 and 1). All I want to do is make this a single polygon, without that diagonal line where the gap is. The one suggestion did not help, or I just did not understand how to proceed.][image: Diagonal line across dark poly in edit mode]
In QGIS, one polygon feature resulted from merger of several adjacent polygons. This one new polygon feature has a single line through it that I would like to eliminate. When hovering over individual nodes in edit mode a balloon displays polygon number, ring number, and vertex number and in this case the adjacent parts of the new polygon have polygon numbers 0 or 1. How do I combine the polygon parts of this new single polygon feature?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am doing this in QGIS.

Comment: Could you add an image of your polygon to your post? It seems to be an issue that the "Digitizing Tool" plugin may be able to fix.

Answer (score 2):

So, I suggest my cartographic approach to solving your problem and its name sounds like “wedge” or “insertion” (I'm not sure that Google will translate it correctly, though ...)

Initial data: two broken adjacent polygons.

1) Polygon into points, for which run the tool: Vector-> Geometry Processing-> Extract vertices;

2) Edit the points, as shown in my screenshot below, i.e. leave the adjacent points unchanged (4 - two each next to numbers 1 and 2);

[image]

3) Run the Vector-> Geometry-processing tool on points-> Delaunay Triangulation ...

see screenshot below;

[image]

4) Select the "wedge", copy it and paste in edit mode into your working layer;

see screenshot below;
[image]

5) Combine the three parts of your polygons into one by running the Vector-> Geoprocessing-> Merge by Basis ... tool, replace it in the original layer

and everything seems to be ...