# Joining non-contiguous polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, snapping

I am trying to `"physically"` join non-contiguous polygons of the same layer to form one (when the polygons are spaced less than 5m), without distorting the original shape.

This is a building layer, the final goal is to simplify their representation by connecting buildings less than 5m from each other.

[image: example]

I know that ArcGIS offers a tool that meets my needs: `"Aggregate polygons"` or something, I tried several solutions like `"snap geometries to layer"` but It doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about buffer by 2.5 m and then buffer by -2.5 m?

Comment: Eric, thank you, it's working fine, Now my problem sounds stupid xD

Comment: Well, debuffering may lead to undesired notches in the former gaps, so make sure whether this really solves your problem.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327254/120129